# How long does "if" command reach?

Tags: python

So i have my rock, paper, scissors project in progress and i have now made it by putting a lot "if" commands there, but how long does the "if", "elif" command reach because the last "if" commands doesn't seem to print the "You lost!".
I just started coding and i hope you get my questions point and could help me.

```
if player == bot:
    print("Draw!")

elif player == "rock":
    if  bot == "paper":
        print("You lost!")

elif player == "scissors":
    if bot == "paper":
        print("You won!")

elif player == "paper":
    if bot == "rock":
        print("You won!")

elif player == "rock":
    if bot == "scissors":
        print("You won!")

elif player == "paper":
    if bot == "scissors":
        print("You lost!")

elif player == "scissors":
    if bot == "rock":
        print("You lost!")
```

Comment: This gets a lot simpler if you use things like `and` and `or`.

Comment: To expand on the answers below-- the reason your code is failing is because once an `if` or `elif` evaluates to `True`, the execution won't go into any more of the `elif` statements at that same level of indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It reaches the end, but the program never goes there.

Try this instead:

```py
if player == "rock":
    if  bot == "paper":
        print("You lost!")
    elif bot == "scissors":
        print("You won!")

elif player == "scissors":
    if bot == "paper":
        print("You won!")
    elif bot == "rock":
        print("You lost!")

elif player == "paper":
    if bot == "scissors":
        print("You lost!")
    elif bot == "rock":
        print("You won!")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `and` and `or` to combine all the cases where you lose into a single case. Then you have

```
if player == bot:
    print("Draw!")
elif (player == "rock" and bot == "paper"
        or player == "paper" and bot == "scissors"
        or player == "scissors" and bot == "rock"):
    print("You lost!")
else:
    print("You won!")
```

Your problem is that `player == "rock"` only gets evaluated once; the outer `if` statement doesn't pick up where you left off if the inner `bot == "paper"` is false.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of more compact code:

```
player = "scissors"
bot = "paper"

hand = ["rock","paper","scissors"]

if player == bot:
    print("Draw!")
elif hand[(hand.index(player) + 1)%3] == bot:
    print("You lost!")
elif hand[(hand.index(player) - 1)%3] == bot:
    print("You won!")
```

The idea is that an element in `hand` always gets beat by the element to the right, the last element loops back to the start.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
if player == bot:
    print(f"Draw")
elif player == "rock":
    if bot == "scissors":
        print("You won!")
    else:
        print("You lost.")
elif player == "paper":
    if bot == "rock":
        print("You won!")
    else:
        print("You lost.")
elif player == "scissors":
    if bot == "paper":
        print("You won!")
    else:
        print("You lost.")
```

Comment: Your indentation seems to be wrong here

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it now. Sorry still not used to formatting things on here :s

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the way you show, you have to group the "sub" ifs under the same if, otherwise it gets skipped:

```
if player == "paper":
  if bot == "rock":
    ...

# more code here ...

elif player == "paper": #this one is skipped, because it already checked if it was paper earlier
```

without changing your aproach, you should do:

```
if player == "paper":
    if bot == "rock":
        # ...
    elif bot == "paper": # notice grouping here under the same first if
        # ...
    #...

elif player == "rock":
    if bot == "paper":
#...
```

or better yer:

`if player == "paper" and bot == "scissior": #...`

But you can do something more compact with something like:

```
# Assume the options are chose as numeric 1-rock, 2-paper, 3-scissor
beats = {1:3, 2:1, 3:2}

while (player := int( input("Choose:\n1-rock\n2-paper\n3-scissors\n> ") or 0 ) ):
    # game keeps going on until empty input
    bot = #whatever you use to generate the bot value
    if player == bot or player not in beats:
        # draw or invalid input
    elif beats.get(player) == bot:
        # the player won
    else:
        # the bot won
```